# How to call flutter code from ios extension

Tags: ios, flutter, unnotificationserviceextension

I would like to call flutter code after i receive ios notification in UNNotificationServiceExtension. It seems i cant use channels from ios extensions.
I would like to execute this code without the need of user to tap on notification.

Sharing nsuserdefaults between dart and swift does not help, because app needs to be opened to detect some new value there.

Any idea?

Comment: An extension is a separate process to your main app; that is why channels don't work. I suspect that you will probably just need to implement your extension code in Swift.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that my dart code scans for Bluetooth devices. Tried that in swift inside extension and it's not working.

Comment: An extension can't use core Bluetooth no matter what you write it in